# Defining Binomial distribution centered at any integer

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, binomial-distribution

Given the Binomial distribution: $$\Pr(k;n,p) = \Pr(X = k) = \binom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
It is clear that for choices of $n$ and $p$ we can shift the binomial distribution left or right since $\mu = np$. I want to consider the case for $p =0.5$, hence the mean and median are equivalent.

Does anyone know if there is an extension of this distribution which allows the distribution to be centered at any integer (including negative of course)? Where centered refers to centering with respect to the mean. This was somewhat addressed in [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572434/generating-a-binomial-distribution-around-zero) but here they are looking for a shift to zero from a programming perspective not analytically.

Thanks.

Comment: "centred" meaning what? Middle of the interval where the probability is nonzero? Mean? Median?

Comment: @Chappers Sorry given that $p = 0.5$ .

Comment: But your figure shows success probabilities of .5, .7, and .9. Your definition of 'center' remains unclear.

Comment: @BruceET I removed the figure and restated the problem with comment to your answer.

Comment: If $p=0.5$ then then $\operatorname{Bin}(2n,p)$ is "centered" at $n.$ Here you can choose $n$ to be any non-negative integer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are saying that you just plug it into the binomial formula? But the binomial formula won't work for if $2n < 0$...In Bruce's answer he suggests a change of variable after considering $Bin(2n,p)$. We then have an explicit formula for $Pr(X = k)$ given by the binomial formula and $Z = X-m +c$, can you see how I could get an explicit formula for $Pr(Z)$. Since $Z = X-m+c$, do I simply define let $Pr(Z)= Pr(X-m+c) := Pr(X)$?

Comment: @Alex : Indeed, it will not work if $n<0,$ but anything that will work then will not give you a binomial distribution but some sort of transformation of a binomial distribution.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes this transformation is what I am looking for. I want to shift this binomial distribution centered (with respect to mean for $p=0.5$) depending on my choice of mean. Do you think my idea in comments will work (it follows from the answer below)? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Alex : That can be done in a number of ways. Suppose $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,p),$ and you want it to be "centered" at $c$ in the sense that the expected value will be $c.$ Then you can just let $Y= X - np + c,$ and then you have $\operatorname{E}(Y) = c. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes this is understood, I define a new random variable $Y = X - np + c$ , this is as in the answer below as well. What I'm interested in is just the probability distribution associated with $P(Y)$, hence would the following be the correct way to write this probability: $$Pr(Y) = Pr(X-np +c) := Pr(X = k)$$where $X \sim B(n,p)$?

Answer (score 4):

As noted by @Chappers, you have not said what you mean by 'centered'.
The mean of a binomial distribution is $np$, the median is (roughly)
a nearby integer, and the mode is (rougly) an integer near $(n+1)p.$ See Wikipedia
for details.

If you want a binomial distribution with a particular mean, then choose
$n$ and $p$ appropriately. If you want an *approximately* binomial
distribution with mean $\mu,$ then perhaps use the Poisson distribution
with mean $\mu.$

If you have a particular shape of binomial distribution in mind (perhaps
as determined by particular choices of $n$ and $p$) but it is not
'centered' to your liking, then perhaps add or subtract a constant
to shift it however you please.
However, I can't immediately think of an application where this kind
of centering a binomial would be useful.

If you have a particular goal in mind, perhaps we could be more helpful
with a clear description of that goal.

*Addendum after revision:* If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(2m, .5),$ then $E(X) = m.$
Let $Y = X - m$ so that $E(Y) = 0.$
Then $Z = Y + c$ has $E(Z) = c$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Var}(Y) = \operatorname{Var}(Z) = 2m/4 = m/2.$
The 'centering' constant $c$ can be positive or negative.

Comment: What I am looking for is an extension of the binomial distribution which allows the in binomial distribution to be centered with regard to the mean (where I assume $p=0.5$) for all integers and not just positive integers as is the usual case. Consider for example the normal distribution, this is a probability distribution which can be centered (with regard to the mean) at any integer.

Comment: Suggest you provide this clarification by editing your Question. The third paragraph of my answer may apply.

Comment: Choices of $n$ and $p$ will change the shape of the binomial distribution and it move the center but it doesn't allow the mean to be centered around negative integers, this is the point. This should just be taken as a mathematical query (hence posted on mathematical stack exchange), how can we modify the function to include this additional feature is my query.

Comment: May the Addendum to my Answer is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. To get an explicit formula for $Pr(Z)$, since $Z = X-m+c$, do I simply define let $Pr(Z)= Pr(X-m+c) := Pr(X)$?